# Any plans for updating the jQuery calendar widget on user profiles?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange looks way more beautiful than the Stack Overflow in 2010, but it seems like jQuery UI survived in the code!

[image]

The site is clever that it only loads jQuery UI when you click on "visited *n* days", but loading the entire jQuery UI library just for the date picker is probably a little bit overkill. Plus 2007 wants their gradient-styled UI elements back.

So any plans on updating this part of the site to match the current design?

Comment: Depends on how many users actually click on that link. I don't imagine it gets a very high click rate. And if it's used very little, the chance of it getting further developer time is slim. (I'd prefer we just drop it completely. It's a useless calendar. It doesn't tell users who care about their streak any information on why they lost their streak, so they just complain about it anyways.)